# Lichtenberg figures inside plastic casing of multicooker

Tags: electrical

I've had to disassemble a multicooker ([this one, specifically](https://www.cdiscount.com/electromenager/petits-appareils-de-cuisson/moulinex-multicuiseur-traditionnel-12en1-rouge-5/f-110202801-mou3045386373369.html?ef_id=WQ2b0gAAAUXhNVQm:20170915111836:s&s_kwcid=AL!639!3!154084347561!!!g!!&cid=search&cm_mmc=SE_mckv!PLA!COR!!CD!689039687!&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIm-Oy6oin1gIVsRbTCh0ZBQaREAQYAyABEgIfwPD_BwE)) because I noticed a lot of condensation in the display/contol unit.

As I was doing so, I saw that the inside of the casing is covered in lichtenberg burn marks.

I haven't had an problem with the cooker, but I'd like to know if this is normal and reasonably safe.

Comment: are you sure they are burn marks ? Take a picture and post them. 
Condensation in the control area - not sealed very well if at all. Any air in there after sealing - will have moisture in it.

Comment: It isn't really sealed at all, there's only a hard plastic casing in that area; I saw that other parts had stains and a grain of rice in there. I'm quite sure that they're burn marks. I think there was a transparent film of gunk over the plastic which was burned in that pattern, unfortunately I wiped it off and have reassembled it to avoid parts loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types of burn marks are an indication of electric current being where it should not be and should definitely **not** be considered normal or safe. You should discontinue use of that appliance unless inspected and repaired at a manufacturer recommended repair shop.